# How to use variable to get the for loop's value in PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop

How to use a varible to store the value of the for loop?

```
for($i=1;$i<=$var;$i++)
```

How to get `$i`'s value and store into another value and show its result?

I am a beginner of PHP and I want to improve my concept, I am very grateful if anyone can helps, Cheers!

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're asking, though it sounds as simple as `for ($i=1; $i<=$var; $i++) { $othervar = $i; echo $othervar; }`

Comment: Assign `$i` to wherever you wish to store it, then echo that variable (though you could just `echo "i has the value of $i";` using `$i` directly)

Comment: I know it should be use the $i directly but I would like to create another varaible to show the $i result out of the for loop: such as use $num to show $i's value (Result: 12345678910 as the $var is 10)

Comment: for($i=1;$i<=$var;$i++){                                                             ....implement $num =$i; //count the $i and show result as 12345678910                                                                  }                                                                              echo $num;                                                              Just like that, thanks everyone to answer and comment my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Are you want dynamic variable or just a normal variable which will give you the out put like 
 12345678910

```
<?php 
$var=10;
$a='';
for($i=1;$i<=$var;$i++){
$a.=$i;
}
echo $a;
?>
```

output: http://3v4l.org/2p8L6

or if you want dynamic variable then use following code to make a variable dynamic

```
${"num_" . $i} = $i;
```

output will be

```
$num_1=1; 
$num_2=2;
$num_3=3;
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

In plain English; PHP is updating the value stored in lopping variable automatically, and this is the whole idea behind using `for` loops, not only in PHP, but also in other programming languages.

Usually, you would want to use it (the variable `$i`) as a kind of a counter, and run code in the loop based on the iteration count.